# printing long string with a single write call

Tags: python

I found a quite unexpected feature(or bug ?) when trying to write a long string with a single `write` call using python (python 2.7.3-32 bit, windows 7).

Calling `print "a"*4000` prints on stdout a line that seems ok but calling `print "a"*5000` just produces a line with 5000 white spaces instead of 'a' character.

Would you have any idea of what is going wrong and how I can circumvent that problem ?

Additional information:

using a newer version of python (2.7.5) still produces the same error. Here is a snippet that produces the aformentionned problem.

```
f = open("toto.dat","w",1000000)
s = "a"*5000
f.write(s)
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

thanks a lot.

Eric

Comment: please indicate the version of Python, your OS and it's system architecture (32 or 64bits). I don't reproduce your problem on IPython 32bits under WinXP.

Comment: It is a 32-bit 2.7.3 version hosted on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: `how I can circumvent that problem` -- assuming that it's a bug in the version you're using, upgrade!

Comment: you right, just tried with a 2.7.5 version and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: @devnull add that as an answer!

Comment: Sorry but performing further tests still produces some errors (even with python 2.7.5). For example, the following scripts produce a file with a first line made of 5000 white spaces.

Comment: I cannot replicate this in `2.6.6`, `2.7.4`, or `3.3.2`, even with 10000+ character strings, but I'm on a 32-bit XP box. `with open(r'C:\test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('a'*10000)` works fine.

Comment: What are you using to inspect the resulting file?  Notepad?  A hex editor?  Something else?

Comment: I use crimson editor. Interestingly, when I open the written file with python and I print, say the 5 first characters, I get "aaaaa", but when I print the whole string, once again it prints nothing. This behaviour occurs within the python shell of eclipse and not when launching the script in a DOS shell.

Comment: And with notepad it works, the whole string is written ... this makes me  crazy ...

Comment: What happens if you write to the file in binary mode? `open('toto.dat', 'wb')` Are the results identical?

Comment: Whatever program you're using to inspect the output file is almost certainly displaying the results incorrectly.  I bet you dollars to donuts that Python is producing the correct output file.

Comment: Surprisingly no, notepad displays correctly the "a" characters. Concerning python, I do think that the file is correctly written but it seems that a single `write` or `print` for such a long string may trigger some trouble at a buffer level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem of buffer ?

Try this please:

```
from os import fsync

fh = open("test.dat","w")
s = "a"*5000
fh.write(s)
fh.write("\n")
fh.flush()
fsync(fh.fileno())
fh.close()
```

There's no reason that closing the file-handler wouldn't empty the buffer and write in the file, as far as I know, but who knows ?....

Comment: Use `with` blocks for file handling? http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @Aleksander Lidtke  I know it's better. But the problem is maybe linked precisely to the fact that he opens and closes himself the file.

Comment: It could, yeah. To be frank I didn't read the entire post, just wanted ti highlight that there are other ways of doing this. Too long + too late + holidays ;)

Comment: No trouble. Have a nice evening.

Comment: I tried to explicitely flush the buffer but this gives the same result: a line with with spaces instead of "a".